# Condicional para múltiples categorías

Tags: php, wordpress, condiciones

Estoy intentando crear un `condicional` para comprobar si la página actual (en este caso una `plantilla personalizada`) está dentro de una `categoría`, de modo que en caso de pertenecer a esa `categoría` entonces, muestra una información diferente, en mi caso mostrará los posts de esa única `categoría`. Para ello he creado lo siguiente que de momento sí funciona, pero le falta algo (esto es un ejemplo):

```
<?php
if(in_category('acuaticos')):
  echo 'Esta página está en la categoría seleccionada';
else:
  echo 'Esta página NOOOO está en la categoría seleccionada';
endif;
?>
```

Actualmente ese código me indica si la página se encuentra o no en esa categoría ¿pero como hago para comprobar lo mismo con el resto de categorías? Tengo mas de 300 categorías y pensaba en crear un `array` con todas las categorías para su comprobación (para pasarlas por la condición), sin embargo no sé como se hace.

Por favor, ¿Alguien me puede orientar? gracias desde ya!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes, primero, colectar todas las categorías que hay, con `get_categories()`, y luego hacer 'loop' sobre estas, por ejemplo:

```
// 1. Buscar todas las categorías que hay
$categories = get_categories();

// 2. Verificar si hay resultados
if ( $categories && !is_wp_error( $categories ) ):

    // 3. Si todo está bien, hacer 'loop'
    foreach ( $categories as $category ):

        // 4. buscar su 'slug', y ponerlo en la condicional que necesitas
        $slug = $category->name;
        if ( in_category( $slug ) ):
            // Hacer X
        else:
            // Hacer Y
        endif;

    endforeach;

endif;
```